# Error in KeyGenerator Java Xml Digital Signature

Tags: java, digital-signature, xml-signature

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data1 = "Test Data";
    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");   //Line 34
    kgen.init(256);
    SecretKey key = kgen.generateKey();
   byte[] keyaes = key.getEncoded();
   byte[] IV = new byte[12];
   SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
   random.nextBytes(IV);

   byte[] encryptedData = encryptgcm(data1.getBytes(), key, IV);
   byte[] encryptedSessionKey = encryptSessionKeyUsingPublicKey(keyaes, "1");

   String xmlDoc = "<DATA>ENCRYPTEDDATA</DATA>";

   String signedDocument = signXmlClient(xmlDoc, true);

   System.out.println("Signed Document : " + signedDocument);

}



Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
        Unhandled exception type NoSuchAlgorithmException
        Unhandled exception type IOException
        Unhandled exception type GeneralSecurityException

        at signXml.main(signXml.java:34)
```

On line 34 am getting an error while generating Key.

I am trying to sign a xml document . Please help in resolving the following issue . Also if someone can give any reference to code the same in vb.net

Comment: Hi & Welcome to [so]! What are the details of `NoSuchAlgorithmException`? ..what jvm are you operating?

Comment: **That's a _compile_ error**; your program is invalid because it doesn't follow the Java rules for exceptions. See for example https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html . @xerx593: since this isn't an exception occurring at runtime it has no data, or stacktrace.

Comment: Aaaah! (compiler error) You said, you get "error **while generating** Key" (...which sounds for me like *runtime*). Easy solution (for the compiler problem): Add `throws NoSuchAlgorithmException` (+ all mentioned) to `main`.